# iPhone 5 Web Browser - transparent .png with black matte

Tags: iphone, css, mobile

I often use 24-bit transparent .png files in web design. I recently checked an iPhone 5, mostly to look at the viewport, and noticed my .png files all have a black matte?

Went back and checked an iPhone 4 and everything looks fine there. Not sure what to say. I've been saving files the same way since 2007! Either a save-for-web from Photoshop or a direct save-as. 
Any ideas? Is mobile Safari the new IE 6?

Comment: Can you show some images? That could make it easier to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this a little more, including testing more than one iPhone5.

It's a colour profile issue saving out of Photoshop. I opened the files and assigned a colour profile (I assigned sRGB to one and colormatch to the other) and they work fine with either.

Normally I use sRGB for all my images, so it's strange, but definitely a local issue to my files, as saved from Photoshop. It doesn't totally make sense to me that the colour profile wasn't there in the first place, but at least I understand this now.

Hope fully it helps someone.